# Proving that the cardinality of an interval is equal to that of the real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show that  (0,1] ~ $\mathbb R$. Here is my attempt:

let $f:(0,1] \to \mathbb R_+$ \ {$0$}, such that $f(x) = -ln(x)$

and let 
$g:R_+ $ \ {$0$}  $\to \mathbb R $, such that $g(x) = ln(x)$

Where f and g are bijective functions.

Then the composite, which is also a bijection, given by:

$$
g~o~f:(0,1]\to\mathbb R :g(x)=ln(-ln(x))
$$

So then, this means that (0,1] ~ $\mathbb R$
That is, they have the same cardinality. Is this proof correct? and what is the best way to usually go about finding these functions to prove these cases, it is quite tedious..

Comment: Your $f$ maps $(0,1]$ to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: The standard example is $\tan \dfrac{\pi}{2} x$. If you can show that all intervals have the same cardinality as $(-1,1)$, then this would be a bijection between $(-1,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For an easy way to avoid the construction of the necessarily discontinuous bijection $(0,1]\to\Bbb R$, you can just use Schroeder-Bernstein on the identity $(0,1]\to\Bbb R$ and an arctangent for $\Bbb R\to(0,1)\subseteq(0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g:\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ be a bijection. Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a strictly decreasing sequence converging to $0$, with $x_1=1.$ For each $n\in \mathbb N $ let the function $f$  map the interval $(x_{n+1},x_n]$ bijectively onto $(g(n),1+g(n)].$ Then $f:(0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is a bijection.

In many cases we use the Cantor-Bernstein (a.k.a. Schroeder-Bernstein, a.k.a.Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein ) Theorem to prove the existence of a bijection:

THEOREM. If $g:A\to B$ is injective and $h:B\to A$ is injective then there exists a bijection $f:A\to B.$

There are two common proofs, one easy and short, the other one, NOT. The easy proof gives an explicit construction for $f$,  given $g$ and $h.$

For example when $A=(0,1]$ and $B=\mathbb R,$ let $g=id_A $ and let $h(x)=  \frac {1}{2} +\frac {1}{\pi}  \tan^{-1}x.$ ( Where the function $\tan^{-1}$ takes values in $(-\pi /2,\pi /2).)$

Answer (score 0):

First map the unit interval to the real line by a tangent-esque function and then argue that adding a point does not change the cardinality for infinite sets (Admittedly I remember giving the same outline to a similar question).